# why tokenize texts in lucene?

Tags: lucene, tokenize

I'm beginner of lucene. Here's my source:

```
ft = new FieldType(StringField.TYPE_STORED);
    ft.setTokenized(false);
    ft.setStored(true);
    ftNA = new FieldType(StringField.TYPE_STORED);
    ftNA.setTokenized(true);
    ftNA.setStored(true);
```

Why tokenized in lucene? For example: the String value of "my name is lee"

- case tokenized, "my" "name" "is" "lee"
- case not tokenized, "my name is lee"

I'dont understand why indexing by tokenized. What is the difference between tokenized and not tokenized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene works by finding *tokens* in *documents* which satisfy constraints expressed by a *query*.

If you search for `lee` for instance, the query will find all documents that contain the *token* `lee`. If the field isn't tokenized, you'll only be able to find `my name is lee`, but not just `lee` for instance.

Now suppose you search for `"is lee"`. This is a `PhraseQuery`, which means it'll match the token `is` followed by the token `lee`.

Tokenization is needed because Lucene works with an *inverted index*, ie it maps *tokens* to the *documents* that contain them.