# Whitespace in regex in ElasticSearch / NEST

Tags: c#, regex, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to write a regex for Regexp where there can be white space in the words. For example I'm trying to run `".*\\suse\\sdefault\\sfor.*"` and It won't give me any results even though I know one of my documents has that phrase. Is there a way to be doing whitespace differently than like this?

Comment: there may be a chance of one or more white spaces present inbetween  `".*\\suse\\s+default\\s+for.*"`

Comment: Neither are working...it is for sure one space between words

Comment: Why don't you use a [`PhraseQuery`](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/phrase-matching.html)? Regexes in Lucene/ElasticSearch are only meant for searching inside *single terms*.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Are you able to put regex in that? Like i'd want to match if you had something like "cause default forward" it would match because use default for is inside of that.

Comment: @Devin here's [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29419930/3764814) for that in Lucene. I think you should be able to adapt it to an ES query. But first, I think you should learn more about [tokenization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29457236/3764814) and analysis in Lucene, so you understand why a regex query won't work in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex query should be `.*use default for.*`

The important part is that the field should be [set as](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html) "not analyzed" at the _mapping

Comment: I think you're missing a bit of `\`` formatting here.